# KeyListener on two dimensional JPanel [][] table

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

I have created a two dimension JPanel table and i have a JButton on my first cell.I wanna move the button with my arrow keys inside the bounds of my table.I have to put KeyListener in every cell or on my button?Maybe you will find my question stupid but i need a little help with the KeyListener.Thank you!![image: Here its what i have to create]

Here is the code i have written!

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

JPanel [][] innerCells;

public MyFrame() {
    JFrame fr = new JFrame("Final Exams");
    fr.setSize(800, 600);

    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fr.setVisible(true);
    fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    JButton b = new JButton("G");
    innerCells = new JPanel[10][10];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            innerCells[i][j] = new JPanel();
            innerCells[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange));
            p.add(innerCells[i][j]);
        }
    }
    innerCells[0][0].add(b);
    fr.add(p);

}
```

Comment: Take a look at **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834765/move-jbutton-with-keyboard-arrows-inside-a-grid-panel/16835242#16835242)**, basically, ignore KeyListener and use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Thank you very much!I will work on it and i will post my answer!;)
So u mean no Listener?Why key bindings is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i manage to solve at last this problem! here is the solution..I have done it with KeyListener but i think as @MadProgrammer says with key bindings its easier!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Askhsh6 {

    int gr, st;
    Dimension dim;

    public Askhsh6() {
        final JFrame fr1 = new JFrame("a Title");
        fr1.setSize(800, 600);
        fr1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr1.setVisible(true);
        fr1.setResizable(false);

        final JButton b = new JButton("G");
        dim = new Dimension(70, 50);
        b.setSize(dim);
        b.setFocusable(false);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                b.validate();
                b.repaint();
                boolean pop = b.isFocusOwner();

                pop = b.isFocusOwner();
                System.out.println("" + pop);
            }
        });
        final JPanel[][] p;
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 6));

        p = new JPanel[8][6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                p[i][j] = new JPanel();
                p[i][j].setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                p[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange));
                p1.add(p[i][j]);

            }
        }
        p[0][0].add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gr = st = 0;

        fr1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("DOWN");
                    if (gr + 1 < 8) {
                        p[gr][st].remove(b);
                        gr = gr + 1;
                        p[gr][st].add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                        fr1.repaint();
                    }
                }
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    System.out.println("UP");
                    if (gr - 1 >= 0) {
                        p[gr][st].remove(b);
                        gr = gr - 1;
                        p[gr][st].add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                        fr1.repaint();
                    }
                }
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    System.out.println("LEFT");
                    if (st - 1 >= 0) {
                        p[gr][st].remove(b);
                        st = st - 1;
                        p[gr][st].add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                        fr1.repaint();
                    }
                }
                if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    System.out.println("RIGHT");
                    if (st + 1 < 6) {
                        p[gr][st].remove(b);
                        st = st + 1;
                        p[gr][st].add(b, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                        fr1.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        fr1.add(p1);
        fr1.validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a keylistener to the button (working with KeyBindings would be better).

Make two int variables for the indices of the current panel (e.g. x,y).

In the keyPressed(KeyEvent e) method
remove the button from the current panel and add it to the new panel.

Note: The button must have focus, if you want to move it with the keys.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel [][] innerCells;
    private JButton b = new JButton("G");
    private int x=0;
    private int y=0;
    private final int size=10;

    public MyFrame() {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Final Exams");
        fr.setSize(800, 600);

        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));

        innerCells = new JPanel[size][size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                innerCells[i][j] = new JPanel();
                innerCells[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.orange));
               p.add(innerCells[i][j]);
            }
        }
        innerCells[0][0].add(b);
        fr.add(p);  

        b.addKeyListener(new KListener());
    }

    private class KListener extends KeyAdapter{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            innerCells[x][y].remove(b);
            innerCells[x][y].repaint();
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            switch( keyCode ) { 
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    x= x-1;
                        break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    x= (x+1)%size;
                        break;

                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    y= y-1;
                        break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT :
                    y= (y+1)%size; 
                        break;
            }
            if(x<0) x=size-1;
            if(y<0)y=size-1;
            innerCells[x][y].add(b);

            innerCells[x][y].revalidate();
            b.requestFocus();
    }
   ´        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yoou mean to add KeyListener in every cell?

Comment: please to delete this answer, 1) did you tried linked code in comment by @MadProgrammer , 2) JFrame by default bever to react for KeyEvents from KeyListener, must be redispathed from AWTEventListener 3) never to use KeyListener for simple KeyEvents, simple KeysShortCuts

Comment: I will not delete this answer because this guy tried to help me even if his answer is wrong.I took just a look on @MadProgrammer's answer.Thank you too!

Comment: @Manolis Karagiannis please to ignore this answer, add JLabels with Icon(instead of moving with real JButton between JPanels), add MouseListener for MouseEvents, KeyBindins for switch between setIcon(IconLooksLikeAsBtton) and setIcon(null)

Comment: @Manolis Karagiannis  and this code never will be works correctly without doLayout() & notify(), sure better with revalidate() and repaint()

Comment: @user2089307 see my last comment to Manolis Karagiannis, and isn't clear that you set JPanel.setFocusable(true) and to re_set JPanel.setFocusable(false) for rest of JPanels into grid

Comment: @mKorbel you mean on user2089307 code?After the line   innerCells[x][y].add(b); or my code????

Comment: @Manolis Karagiannis (talking about KeyListener and KeyBindings) only one of JPanels in the grid can be JPanel.setFocusable(true) or added KeyBindings, only to the JPanel that held JButton, is added,  rest omust be changed to JPanel.setFocusable(false), 2, JButton is removed from one JPanel, then, laterr JButton is added to JPanel, without revalidate & repaint, wrong put JButtons to all JPanels and to play with setVisible(true/false) only

Comment: @user2089307 but there were some progress, please don't to delete this question +1 against i.d.i.o.t.s (maybe will protect this question)

Comment: @mKorbel I forgot revalidate/repaint. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Guys don't fight!Is that answer correct or not?That's the point!

Comment: not an correct answer, never to use low_lever Listeners without important reasons, important reason will be keys short cuts with three or mode key pressed/releassesd in the same time, there isn't any important reason, then to use top abstraction as is possible, in this case is there KeyBindings, more in the Oracle tutorial :-), JComponents must be fosusable or focus owner for KeyListener, otherwise you are focus hunter, focussing in settable parameters implemented in KeyBindings, on 1st sight is KeyListener easier, but only, code with same funcions is longer

Comment: Your answer my friend @user2089307 is not working!sorry about that!I just tryied that.Dear mKorbel you are right!

Comment: Sorry for the waiting. My first solution was on the fly. I wrote a working solution for you ;). BUT mKorble is right. You should use Keybindings in this spot and removing/adding buttons permanently isn't nice either.