# Changing the positions of two components in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a panel with GridLayout and with some components in it. Below, there is an example of the code.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

JButton[] buttons = new JButton[5];
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
   buttons[i] = new JButton(i + "");
   panel.add(buttons[i]);
}
```

What I want is to be able to swap the positions of these buttons in the example, I tried to write a method for it. But the only way I managed to do it was removing all of them, then adding in the right order. So are there any better ways writing the method `swap(int index1, int index2)` to swap two components in a grid layout panel?

Comment: Have you tried [`JComponent#setComponentZOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setComponentZOrder(java.awt.Component,int))? For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834765/move-jbutton-with-keyboard-arrows-inside-a-grid-panel/16835242#16835242)

Comment: This seems to be doing what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove just those two buttons, and re-add them using the [add method which takes an index](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component,int%29).

```
static void swap(Container panel,
                 int firstIndex,
                 int secondIndex) {

    if (firstIndex == secondIndex) {
        return;
    }

    if (firstIndex > secondIndex) {
        int temp = firstIndex;
        firstIndex = secondIndex;
        secondIndex = temp;
    }

    Component first = panel.getComponent(firstIndex);
    Component second = panel.getComponent(secondIndex);

    panel.remove(first);
    panel.remove(second);

    panel.add(second, firstIndex);
    panel.add(first, secondIndex);
}
```

Caution: Order matters when adding.  Always add the lower index first.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wanted to do.